# texlive update - Command to update directory owned by other user fails to chdir

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, latex

I've installed Tex Live manually. To update, some documentation recommended assigning the install directory to a user (tex), then updating using the following command:
alias update-tex='sudo -u tex -E $(which tlmgr) update --self --all'

I gave /usr/local/texlive/ as the home directory of user tex.

Now, it gives an error "chdir error", if I run my command from the home directory of my user (waymore), but not if I'm in /usr/local/telive.

How can I fix this so I can run the command from anywhere?

Here's my output below

```
[waymore@archlaptop ~]$ update-tex 
tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.quantum5.ca/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: chdir(/home/waymore) failed: Permission denied at /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 714.
[waymore@archlaptop ~]$ cd /usr/local/texlive/
[waymore@archlaptop texlive]$ update-tex 
tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.quantum5.ca/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
[1/4, ??:??/??:??] update: babel [2106k] (69050 -> 69085) ... done
[2/4, 00:04/00:06] update: bookmark [491k] (69081 -> 69084) ... done
```